# How data is transferred into device memory from host memory in OpenCL?

Tags: architecture, operating-system, opencl, gpu, nvidia

I have a ATI RV770 graphics card and i am using OpenCL 1.0 AMD-APP-SDK-v2.5 to run OpenCL programs.

To transfer data from host memory to device memory i am using

```
d_A = clCreateBuffer ( context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY , partition_size * sizeof(datatype),NULL, &err); checkStatus("Failed to create device input buffer A  ",err);
err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer ( cmd_queue, d_A, CL_TRUE, 0, partition_size * sizeof(datatype), &h_A, 0, 0 , 0); checkStatus("Failed to copy data from host to device ",err);
```

My question is how data is copied into device memory (bitwise or bytewise or >= 32bits-wise)??

Assume i have h_A of the following struct type::

```
typedef struct abc{int a; unsigned char ch[64]; } ABC;
```

and i want to transfer 1000 elements ABC struct type,

Can i transfer data of struct type? If yes then how data will be copied into device memory?

In general, what are the indeed characteristic require for movement of data within computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no restrictions on what you can write to the device memory.
Your implementation is free to copy in whatever chunks it can handle best, but it will only write as many bytes as you tell it to.

As for structs:

You may have to take care of different padding used in your host compiler and the OpenCL compiler.
The easiest way around this is to use a 1-byte alignment on the host struct (check your compiler instructions, happens to be the same for GCC) and use `__attribute__ ((packed))` on the struct in the kernel code. Also make sure you use the proper `cl_*` types in your host code to ensure proper padding.

**Host** (GCC):

```
struct __attribute__ ((packed)) ABC
{
    cl_int a;
    cl_uchar ch[64];
};
```

**Kernel**:

```
struct __attribute__ ((packed)) ABC
{
    int a;
    unsigned char ch[64];
};
```

You can also use a specific alignment value if you know that no alignment (packed attribute) will impact performance. The alignment has to be the same on the host and in the kernel. This might be tricky in some cases:

> Note that the effectiveness of aligned attributes may be limited by
>   inherent limitations of the OpenCL device and compiler. For some
>   devices, the OpenCL compiler may only be able to arrange for variables
>   to be aligned up to a certain maximum alignment.

However, if you already know the effect of alignment on a specific hardware, chances are you know the alignment limitations as well.

[Here](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/attributes-types.html)'s a little bit of text from the spec about the attributes.

Comment: Specifically since the OP mentioned AMD SDK: they have an annoying bug in how their compiler interprets memory layout of aligned structs within unions: http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/158559